# Create SQLAlchemy engine like pyodbc.connect()?

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy

i have set up a connection to sql server using pyodbc but now i try to connect it using sqlalchemy but i get this error

```
raise exc.ArgumentError(
sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Could not parse rfc1738 URL from string 'Driver={sql server};Server=L39;Database=master;Trusted_Connection=true;'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

this what i do for pyodbc and work good

```
import pyodbc
conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={sql server};'
                      'Server=L39;'
                      'Database=master;'
                      'Trusted_Connection=true;')
```

i need to do it by something like this

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine()
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have a working ODBC connection string

```py
connection_string = (
    'Driver=ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server;'
    'Server=L39;'
    'Database=master;'
    'Trusted_Connection=Yes;'
)
```

you can easily use that to create a SQLAlchemy Engine:

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.engine import URL

connection_url = URL.create(
    "mssql+pyodbc",
    query={"odbc_connect": connection_string}
)
engine = create_engine(connection_url)
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL Alchemy uses a *URL* to connect, not a connection string (which is what `pyodbc` expects).

Here's the documentation you need: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/engines.html#microsoft-sql-server

Copying the pertinent snippets here for posterity:

> The typical form of a database URL is:
>
> ```
> dialect+driver://username:password@host:port/database
> ```

> The SQL Server dialect uses pyodbc as the default DBAPI. pymssql is also available:
>
> ```py
> # pyodbc
> engine = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://scott:tiger@mydsn')
>
> # pymssql
> engine = create_engine('mssql+pymssql://scott:tiger@hostname:port/dbname')
> ```

Comment: so i cant connect sql server with sqlalchemy ? if i can from where i get my url